# Is there an explanation why the verb "aufhören" is derived from the verb "hören"?

Tags: verb, separable-verb

Is there an explanation why the verb "aufhören" which means "to stop" is derived from the verb "hören" (to hear)? Or, is it just a pure coincidence?

Comment: Related [general question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/7117/1696), how prefixes change meaning.

Answer (score 12):

## Synchronic view

(*Synchronic* meaning: Looking at the language as it is now.)

The meanings of particle verbs are **in principle** independent of their verbal bases.

> fallen (to fall) – ausfallen (to be cancelled)
>   lehnen (to lean) – ablehnen (to reject)
>   nehmen (to take) – aufnehmen (to record)
>   wenden (to turn over) – aufwenden (to spend)
>   greifen (to grip) – angreifen (to attack)

This is the group *aufhören* belongs to. The assumption that *aufhören* is independent from *hören* is supported by the fact that *aufhören* allows inanimate subjects and infinitives with *zu*, whereas *hören* does not.

> Der Regen hörte auf.
>   Die Wunde hörte nicht auf zu schmerzen.

Of course, there are also many cases where the particle and the verb combine transparently.

> schalten, einschalten, ausschalten, umschalten  (switch, switch on, switch off, switch from... to...)
>   atmen, einatmen, ausatmen (breathe, breathe in, breathe out)
>   bauen, aufbauen, abbauen (build, assemble, dismantle)

And you can build groups of verbs where the particle seems to add a similar meaning.

> (*auf* meaning *from the ground*)
>   aufsammeln, aufwischen, aufschlecken, auflesen
>
> (*auf* indicating that an event is suddenly coming to be perceived)
>   aufschreien, aufheulen, aufleuchten, aufblitzen

## Diachronic view

(*Diachronic* meaning: Looking at the history of the language.)

You can look at etymological dictionaries if you are interested in how the meaning developed historically.

For example, the Brothers Grimm [observed](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=aufhoeren) that there are dialects that use *hören* in the meaning of *aufhören*. They also note that *gehorchen*, derived from *horchen* (*to hearken*), evolved to mean *to obey*. They cite examples from Luther to show that he already used *aufhören* in the contemporary meaning.

As they speculate:

> Wie der hörende *anhört*, audit ad dominum, *ihm angehört*, (lat. mit dem sinne des auges statt des ohres aufgefaszt, *spectat ad dominum*); ebenso *hört er auf*, attendit ad vocem, paret verbo, verrichtet das gebotene, unterläszt das verbotene, *hör auf!* desine!

Comment: Du schreibst zuerst sinngemäß »es gibt keinen Zusammenhang« und lieferst 3 Absätze später erste Indizien für genau den Zusammenhang, nach dem gefragt wurde?

Comment: In der synchronen Perspektive gibt es keinen Zusammenhang. Diachron läßt sich eventuell einer finden.

Comment: Jetzt ist es eine gute Antwort. Daher: +1

Comment: Very good to distinguish synchronic and diachronic perspective her. However, I'd say that the relation from _aufnehmen_ to _nehmen_ is clear also in synchronic view.

Comment: A synchronic perspective won't give an explanation why *aufhören* is derived from *hören*, and it doesn't say anything about coincidence either.

Comment: I can see a pretty direct (at least figurative) connection between *all* of the examples you list in the "Synchronic View" section, unlike it is the case with "hören/aufhören".

Comment: If you know the meaning of both the base verb and the particle verb, you can of course invent an explanation that connects them. These are completely subjective, though. Note how O. R. Mapper feels no direct connection between the meanings of *hören* and *aufhören*, whereas Christian Geiselmann does. This is quite different from semantically transparent derivations such as *un-sicher, Schön-heit, Mess-ung, Programmier-er*, where no such subjectivity exists. I am hesitant to add to the answer; I feel that semantic transparency and compositionality would warrant a new question.

Comment: +1 for the link to the fantastic Wörterbuchnetz site!

Comment: " there are also many cases where the particle and the verb combine transparently." What do you mean by transperantly?

Comment: @SBrian [Transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_(linguistic)#Definition) is a linguistic term that signifies that the meaning of the whole is derivable from the meaning of the parts. *Aufhören* is non-transparent or opaque in that knowing the meaning of *auf* and of *hören* is not sufficient to derive the meaning *stop, cease*. On the other hand, there are many combinations of *ein* and *aus* with verbs that are transparent: *(ein/aus)atmen, -packen, -steigen, -laden* etc. *breathe in/out, (un)wrap, get in/out, (un)load*.

Answer (score 8):

### [hören](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GH12401#XGH12401)

Like in English [*hören/hear*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?page=1&q=hear) has common etymologic roots that always meant more than a simple acoustic listening. It is also used widely in the meaning of *to follow, to obey*, and in German also *to belong* (e.g. *gehören, zugehörig sein, hörig sein*).

To hear on something also meant to **follow an action with attention**.

### [auf-](https://dwds.de/wb/auf-)

The prefix [**auf-**](https://dwds.de/wb/auf-) which in German among other meanings<sup>*</sup> is used to designate a termination or a fulfilment of a process (e.g. *aufessen, aufarbeiten, aufklären, aufkündigen, aufgeben*).

<sup>*</sup><sub>Much to the confusion of learners the prefix auf-can even have an almost opposite meaning such as in [aufhorchen](https://dwds.de/wb/aufhorchen)</sub>.

### [auf-hören](https://dwds.de/wb/aufh%C3%B6ren)

If we combine this prefix with *hören* as in *aufhören*, we come to the meaning of *to stop listening*, or *to stop paying attention*.

In modern usage this meaning of *to stop following an action* became more generalized in  *to stop a continued action* as a whole.

Comment: You meander your way exactly around the actual target. See my alternative explanation for the genesis of *aufhören* as *stop doing something* below.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest an explanation for the semantic construct of ***aufhören*** in the meaning of ***stop doing something*** based on situational logic:

Imagine this very typical situation in any society in the olden days: people sitting together in a room and doing something productive, e.g. sewing clothes (in a taylor's shop), or copying a book (as scribes in a monastery). Everybody is concentrated on his task. Enters a chiefly figure (the master taylor, or the abbot), calling:

> Alle mal herhören!

or whatever such command to make them listen to the important words that are going to follow. People now put down their needles or pens and look up (!) towards the superior, waiting for his words. What they actually do is

> aufhören

which is initially and **primarily** not *stop doing something*, but simply *listening up*. You may see heads being raised, and eyes and ears being turned towards the expected source of communication.

As this intensified form of listening is typically (and almost necessarily) accompanied by interrupting any current occupation, that's how *aufhören* got a **secondary meaning**, namely *stopping to do something*.

**Reference**

1) Grimm

The *Deutsches Wörterbuch* by Grimm (here Vol 1. Col. 670 ff) discusses the etymology of *aufhören* at length, testing variuos explanations, but here is a piece of it that would support my theory:

> [...] Auch die heutige schweizerische und bairische volkssprache gebrauchen noch hören für aufhören: nu hör einist = nun lasz ab, hör auf; er cha nit höre = kann nicht ablassen, aufhören (Stald. 1, 54); hoir! = lasz ab, hör auf (Schm. 2, 233). dem haupteindruck nach stimmt das zu dem hören = gehorchen anderer gegenden: das kind will gar nicht hören = nicht gehorchen, denn wenn es gehorcht, läszt es vom verbotnen ab.

This is of course not a direct proof of my

> *aufhören* = to listen up - and as a consequence stop doing other things

but it gives an independent example of exactly this situation: the child, when listening, will stop doing other things it was doing hitherto. (Even more so the dog, by the way.)

2) English *listen up*

The very fact that there is an English expression *to listen up* supports the theory of *aufhören* = *listen up - and stop doing other things*. It has different lexical roots (hear vs listen), but it uses the same situational and semantical logic of "raising one's ears" (possibly as an analogy to "raising one's eyes").

Comment: Is there any reference to support this or is this your personal observation?

Comment: It was genuine thought of my own. But I add a reference to Grimm, for your entertainment and intellectual satisfaction.

Comment: Thank you, that would be great. I may just have misread the Grimm for that peculiar fact. Other people who come here also may like to read about it.

Comment: I am not sure whether I'd like to follow this rather speculative approach here. I think, you mix it up with _aufhorchen_ a bit.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach  I hope I made clear that *aufhören* in the sense of *aufhorchen* / *listening up* is not actually used (any more), but that I see this understanding of *aufhören* as an underlying (tacit) semantical structure to explain the modern use of *aufhören* vor *stop doing something*. As other explanations have not been provided ("they are cognates" is not an explanation, and other attempts here were simply self-contradicting), I think this one is the most promising one.

Answer (score 1):

The following might be an explanation:

> Peter sitzt in einer Vorlesung und langweilt sich. Eben deswegen fängt er an, ein Porträt seiner Sitznachbarin in sein Notizbuch zu zeichnen. Er ist schon ziemlich weit gekommen, da wechselt der Professor zu einem Thema, das ihn interessiert: Er *horcht/hört auf*, legt seinen Stift weg und hört der Vorlesung gebannt zu.

*Hören* and *horchen* must originally have had a wider meaning than anything we do with our ears, but rather (or, in addition) denoted obedience and belonging (you *belong* to a group when you follow common orders). Composites like *angehören*, *gehören*, *aufhören*, *gehorchen* and *Gehorsam* are hints to that. Some of this original meaning is still present when we say of someone's dog

> der hört aber gut!

and don't praise its ears, but rather mean it's well-trained and obedient. *Aufhören* does thus have the original meaning that someone stops following orders and does something else.

This BTW seems to be a common pattern in many Germanic languages:

- Swedish *upphöra*
- Danish *ophøre*
- Norwegian *opphøre*

Comment: You are close, but you miss the target anyway. *Aufhören* is *listening up*, and who listens up usually stops other current activities. See my answer below.

Comment: The North Germanic words are all borrowed or calqued from High or Low German.

Comment: @fdb No. Dutch has it different.

Comment: @tofro. I wrote "or". That is trying to be careful.